# Twilio issue with task sitting in "Wrapping Up"

Tags: twilio

I'm testing out a new phone system design using Twilio TaskRouter, Studio, and Functions.  I've gotten to the point that I can finish the call, but the task sits in "Wrapping Up" and won't allow a new call from the queue to go to the worker associated with that task until I physically delete that task.  I've looked everywhere on how to close the task (get out of Wrapping Up), but can't find any good documentation anywhere.

I have a URL for the "Event Callbacks" of the TaskRouter and can capture exactly when the call moves to this EventType "task.wrapup", but don't know what to do at this point to move it past this step so it releases the task and worker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, with a little more digging I found the solution.  For anyone coming here and having the problem I was having, here is the answer.

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
let client = context.getTwilioClient();

switch(event.EventType) {
    case 'task.wrapup':
        let workspaceId = 'WSxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        console.log(event.TaskSid);
        client.taskrouter.workspaces(workspaceId)
             .tasks(event.TaskSid)
             .update({
                assignmentStatus: 'completed',
                reason: 'Call completed'
              })
             .then(task => {
                 callback(null, twiml);
             })
             .catch(err => {
                 console.log(err);
                 callback(null, twiml);
             });
        break;

    default:
        callback(null, twiml);
        break;
}
};
```

Hope this helps someone else :D

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issues and came up with this solution. It's client-side Javascript based and using Twilio's taskrouter.js:

```
function registerTaskRouterCallbacks() {
  worker.on("reservation.wrapup", function(reservation) {
    worker.completeTask(reservation.task.sid,
      function(error,completedTask) {
        // Do stuff here if needed
      });
  });
}

window.onload = function() {
  // Initialize TaskRouter.js on page load using window.workerToken -
  // a Twilio Capability token that was set in a <script> in associated web page (PHP, etc.) script
  window.worker = new Twilio.TaskRouter.Worker(workerToken);
  registerTaskRouterCallbacks();
};
```